# How do you figure out the exact antecedent to be explained by next qualifier(phrase)?

Tags: antecedents

I'm reading a book named 'the spotify play.' and then looking this sentences I wondered how people could figure out the exact antecedent explained by next qualifier(phrase)

Please look this example.

> Another source would point out that the heads of Universal would have been uneasy about Google, another tech giant, wielding even more influence over their industry, having already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016.

In the text, I think people can understand the antecedent of this phrase (wielding even more influence over their industry, having already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016.) in two way.

First is  which means the head of Universal music label

The second is <Google, another tech giant>.

In my case, I already have background knowledge that Google acquired Youtube in the past so I assumed it was Google, but do people figure out this antecedent only by its context of the text?

Please give me some hint or explanation for this question
Thank you!

*Source: 'The Spotify Play' written by Sven Carlsson and Jonas Leijonhufvud p.86

Comment: There could be confusion about the antecedent in some unwieldy sentences (in which case context should come to the rescue), but here it's quite clear that the antecedent is  _Google_.

Comment: I don't follow you. Are you suggesting that the expression "wielding even more influence over their industry, having already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016" has an antecedent?

Comment: Are you asking who the understood subject of ‘wielding’ is or who the pronoun *their* refers to?

Comment: @user405662 Are you talking about who the understood subject of ‘wielding’ is or who the pronoun *their* refers to?

Comment: Why would Universal be uneasy about Universal (itself) wielding more influence, even if it was the meaning of the sentence structure?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore The former. I don't think antecedent is the right term for it. Yes, I mean the subject of the gerund-participle clause _wielding..._

Comment: @user405662 Well, when there isn't an actual subject (here, there is. It's just separated from the verb by the parenthetical *another tech giant*), it's often referred to as *control.* [See here, for example](https://era.ed.ac.uk/handle/1842/37779)

Comment: Yes, we are always permitted to apply logic to our reading. Universal cannot be wielding influence over itself (their own industry).

Comment: It would be far clearer if the offsetting punctuation around the appositive parenthetical << another tech giant >> was switched to brackets or dashes in the original. But in fact a clearer rewrite is << Another source would point out that the heads of Universal would have been uneasy about Google (another tech giant) wielding even more influence over their industry (Google had already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That looks like an answer masquerading as a comment!

Comment: To answer the actual question, usually you can't. When deletions are made to a sentence, information is lost; quite often, for instance, you can't tell singular from plural subjects (though that  information is of minimal use in English). Infinitives, participles, and contractions and deletions in tensed clauses lose billions of referents every day, and there's no way to figure them out in time to understand the sentence as spoken. If it's not spoken, it's hopeless anyway.

Comment: @Araucaria I feel that such a parochial answer is too insubstantial, and that an attempt at comprehensiveness would prove too demanding.

Comment: The sentence is incorrect. This is what it’s saying, but it’s not what is meant: *Having already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016, the heads of Universal would have been uneasy about Google wielding even more influence over their industry.* (That is, it has the heads acquiring YouTube. In any case, *the heads* is the antecedent for *their* and clearly can’t be the antecedent for *its*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat You’re reading it as if *wielding* was a subjectless gerund-participle clause. However, it isn’t! It has an expressed subject - *Google*. See Edwin’s paraphrase above or the discussion under LPH’s (deleted) answer.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — Yes, I know what is meant. However, the placement of *having already acquired...* forces it to refer to *the heads*. The only way to save the sentence without rewording is to put *having already acquired...* next to *Google*: *Another source would point out that the heads of Universal would have been uneasy about Google (having already acquired YouTube and its music rights in 2016) wielding even more influence over their industry.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat It doesn't force that reading at all! The adjunct *having ...2016* is a modifier of the gerund-participle clause, not the matrix one. Granted, it could be ambiguous between the two if we did not know the meaning (i.e. it could instead be a modifier of the larger matrix clause), but there is absolutely nothing in the grammar to force that alternative, unintended reading.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — The sentence is structurally the same as this train wreck: *The mice were upset about the cat stealing their cheese, having opened the refrigerator.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, and it's ambiguous in the same way (or rather, it's more ambiguous because there's less in the pragmatics to help a reader out).

Comment: Key words: EVEN MORE and ALREADY. Sometimes the little words are the big words.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of that sentence is as follows:

Universal is in the music industry (as well as other entertainment industries: movies, TV).

In 2016, Google aquired YouTube. This acquisition included YouTube's music rights.

As a result of this, Google wields more influence over the music industry than they already did due to their dominance in searching and advertising.

The heads of Universal would have been uneasy about Google because of this.

---

"another tech giant" is a parenthetical comment. So what the heads are uneasy about is "Google weilding even more influence".

The antecedent of "their" is "the heads of Universal". However, I determined this from context and understanding of the situation. Grammatically it's ambiguous, it could have referred to Google.

Comment: Thank you for explanation!

Answer (score 0):

> How do you figure out the exact antecedent to be explained by next qualifier(phrase)?

The answer is that you don't because you can't.

Often there is no obvious cure for poor writing and/or lack of context. That you see an ambiguity is sufficient to classify the example as "poor writing".

To illustrate this point:

**"Tom met Harry and he gave him his book."**

The question is "Who gave whose book to whom?"

In your original, if you are aware of the history of Google and Universal, it will make sense to you.

In my example, if you are aware that Tom had borrowed Harry's book and was returning it, it will make sense to you.

Comment: "poor writing" can be relative to the intended audience. If someone uses industry jargon it will not be understandable to someone outside the industry. But that doesn't make it poor writing if the intended audience is industry members.

Comment: @Barmar I would ask that you look again at the example. If you can see ambiguity - and you say as much - that is enough for the writing to be "poor". Good writing is not ambiguous. We work with what we are given. The author has attempted to supply information and has failed and left confusion. It is poor.

Comment: I don't know where the quote comes from, or what context led up to it.

Comment: @Barmar I think that is my point. The ambiguity is caused by a lack of context and failure to provide context is poor writing. There is no need to delve further. We share the OP's puzzlement - the writing is poor.

Comment: My point was that the context could be implicit. If you're a layman trying to read a document intended for someone in in an industry, you're not expected to be able to understand it, and that's not a fault of the writing. We have no idea where this material was quoted from, it could be intended for someone who knows the relationships between these companies.

Comment: Have a look at Edwin Ashworth's comment "It would be far clearer ... But in fact a clearer rewrite is ..." *It is unclear; it is poor.* I think we will have to agree to differ.

Comment: Oh! Thanks It's helpful!